# How to stop a timer during hibernate/ sleep mode in C# winform application?

Tags: c#, winforms, desktop-application

I have an application which does a specific task after some time (controlled by a timer). But whenever I start PC after hibernate that application runs. This means that timer keeps running during hibernation for atleast one tick. How can I avoid this.

Comment: Just to get this right, the timer is within the (c#?) application you wrote. You start your application, which starts the timer. You then put your pc (assuming windows os) to sleep/hibernate. After a time period longer than your timer, you restart your computer and the application tick event occured. Now you want to know, how to prevent the timer from 'ticking', while your pc is hibernating. Correct?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can handle the SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged event to stop the timer when the machine is suspending and start it again when it is resuming.

```
 SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged += SystemEvents_PowerModeChanged;
```

...

```
 void SystemEvents_PowerModeChanged(object sender, PowerModeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Mode == PowerModes.Suspend) PauseTimer();
        else if (e.Mode == PowerModes.Resume) ResumeTimer();
    }
```

Comment: what is purpose for SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged += SystemEvents_PowerModeChanged;

Comment: This is event/delegate assignment. Whenever the event `SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged` is fired, the method `SystemEvents_PowerModeChanged` will get called, with the mode in the parameter `e`, which is passed into the function. Have not verified this, but seems like a plausible solution.

Comment: One important thing to note from the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.powermodechanged%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) for the `SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged` event is that you'll need to detach the event handler when your application is disposed: `SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged -= SystemEvents_PowerModeChanged;`.